# Pronunciation difference between waist and waste

Tags: pronunciation

I played both words on Google translate and they sound exactly the same.
I checked YouTube and there is [a video](https://youtu.be/7yi0USfAYd8) that is supposed to show the difference but nothing that I could notice plus a other video of English speaker saying [both sound the same](https://youtu.be/FHTY3PrDfbs).

So, regardless the context where the words are used, is there a way to notice the difference between those words when they are pronounced?

Comment: There is no difference, either in the video or by real people.

Comment: @Mitch hey Mitch, why do you answer in a comment, and not in an answer? Just wondering...

Comment: You could look at the pronunciations given by reputable dictionaries.

Comment: I have no doubt that there are people who will claim they pronounce them differently.  But it's unlikely that an impartial observer can tell the difference.  You tell them apart based on context, which is a common need with many parts of English.

Comment: (Consider that in many cases the context of a spoken word will affect it's real or apparent pronunciation far more than the specific homophone spoken.)

Comment: @Jelila not worth it

Comment: @Mitch why not?

Comment: @Jelila why do you ask?

Comment: @Jelila not saying it's the case here, but since you can't downvote comment, normally people add answers in the comments section.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks @vianna77  You can't get voted up either, though...!

Comment: Just wondered @Mitch because, if good and correct answers are in the comments, which is often the case, one cannot see that the question has been answered, and this reduces the usefulness of the system for those who want answers, I perceive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are homophones. They're homophones in my dialect of AmE. They're homophones according to all the dictionaries I have checked (including the OED), which list /weɪst/ as the IPA pronunciation for both words in both BrE and AmE. And they've been homophones for a long time (see [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=GewHAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA55) from 1818).

There are countless jokes out there that rely on the fact that these words are pronounced the same way:

- "Orion's Belt is a huge waist of space" –[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dadjokes/comments/3yfvty/orions_belt_is_a_huge_waist_of_space/)
- "A waist is a terrible thing to mind." (An example of a [transpositional pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpositional_pun))
- [This meme](http://memebase.cheezburger.com/puns/tag/waist)
- [This comic](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/94/de/d6/94ded6a07e75c5d08c0e8c87696d384d--domics-comics-funny-comics.jpg)

Except for jokes like these that purposefully blur the line, it is almost always very obvious which one is meant in conversation because of **context** (and also tone of voice, to some extent). Sometimes the two words are confused in writing, and it's still obvious which is meant because of context.

---

I am not sure the point of that video you linked that "compares" the pronunciation. (However, although somewhat implied, it does not actually say that there is a difference.)

Comment: The links are there to show that I did some research. I normally add some videos and articles comparing two views so people with the same question can compare info.